# Unable to publish Web API from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, webapi

I have created a simple web API in ASP.NET Core and wanted to publish to Azure Web App.
I'm using free trial subscription and have only one web app resource created in Azure.
The app service plan is using free tier 'D1' SKU and is the only one present in my subscription.
However, while trying to publish the web API by choosing this web app in Visual Studio publish profile, it says 'there are no existing instances available'.

The web app resource does appear here:

[image]

Clicking next while the resource is selected, results in the issue:

[image]

Comment: Hey @sandy I was able to publish an api through visual studio in the free tier , please restart and refresh the visual studio or create new resource or provide more info so that I can debug

Comment: I restarted Visual Studio, machine itself, recreated Web App and still no luck :(

Comment: I do have another Enterprise subscription from my organization, this too fails with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have created a .Net Core Web App in the Azure free trial Subscription with free tier plan

[image]

- Initially it contains only `hoststart.html`

***KUDU Console of Initial App Service***

[image]

- Created a sample .Net Core Web API Application in Visual Studio and tried to Publish to the App Service which I have created in Azure portal
- Make sure you have login to the same subscription in Visual Studio where you have created the web app in Portal
- Initially it was prompted to re-enter the credentials after changing the Azure Subscription,I have refreshed the Visual Studio , after few seconds Iam able to see the correct Subscription details.
- Iam able to see the App Service which I have created in Portal

[image]

- Able to successfully deploy the WebAPI to the App service in Portal

***KUDU Console of App Service after Publishing the WebAPI from Visual Studio***
[image]

***Deployed WebAPI Output***

[image]

***Update***

You are in the correct path, after selecting the web app it asks to create the api.Click on the + symbol and add the API Management

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I deleted the web app resource and created a new one with a different location hoping Visual Studio might pick it up and al went in vain

Comment: See the screenshots to my post i just added

Comment: please check for the update in the posted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you created a **Web API** resource and no **API Management** resources. Those two are independent Azure services. Former is needed to host your API application. The other one provides additional features to your APIs and is completely optional - you can look it up in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/).

The step to select/configure API Management resource was introduced in deployment wizard at some point. It is confusing and probably could be handled differently.

Unless you need API Management resource, just skip the step and you'll have deployment profile ready.

[image: Skip API Management selection step]

Answer (score 0):

Just skip it! click 'skip this step', it will be published.